# SignalR Azure New Account wont integration issues

Tags: azure, signalr

we have hired a recent graduate who spoke highly of Azure over other competitors, so I opened the business Azure Account. however he couldn't create our app on my account.

Yet he says he could do it on his university student account - we would rather have everything on board our our business account and not employee account.

Now could you help as to why this would be the case ?

one is  tier student account which seems to have more access and other is the one I made.

Student Account

[image]

Business Account

[image]

How do I allow functionality on business azure account?

Comment: Hello. What problem do you have? Is on creating the Azure SignalR service or it don't even show as a option to create? Add more details to your question please.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Here;s the summary 

Our dev has replicated his work that he has done on his student account, on our azure account which has a free subscription trial at the moment, the free subscription trial sum is going down indicating that there are activity going within the function app resource, but when using signalR on our azure account we're getting an error 401 unauthorized on our application, but if we connect to the student azure using the same function app and signalR there are no errors and it works fine.